# RSpec testing database index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Is there a way to test if a database index exists with RSpec?

I'm using `friendly_id` [gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) and often I forget to create the database index for slug field. 
So, I would like to include this in my RSpec tests.

Comment: Yes, check out [shoulda gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers#activerecord-matchers)

Comment: I'm already using shoulda-matchers. But did not find the matcher that I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`index_exists?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/index_exists%3F) check `unique` by options `unique: true`:

```
=> ActiveRecord::Migration.index_exists?(:users, :user_id, unique: true)
=> -- index_exists?(:users, :user_id)
=>   -> 0.0559s
=> false
```

or:

```
=> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.index_exists?(:users, :user_id)
=> false
```

or [`based on should-matchers`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/have_db_index_matcher.rb#L141):

```
=> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.indexes(:users).map(&:columns)
=> [["birthday"],
=> ["confirmation_token"],
=> ["email"],
=> ["facebook_id"],
=> ["reset_password_token"]]
```

with `unique`:

```
=>ActiveRecord::Base.connection.indexes(:users).map { |x| Hash[:unique, x.unique, :column, x.columns ] }
=> [{:unique=>false, :column=>["birthday"]},
=> {:unique=>true, :column=>["confirmation_token"]},
=> {:unique=>true, :column=>["email"]},
=> {:unique=>true, :column=>["facebook_id"]},
=> {:unique=>true, :column=>["reset_password_token"]}]
```

Comment: Will be best to test the query that is supposed to use the index.