# how do I use index_exists? in rails, NoMethodError: undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, indexing

I'm trying to use the following method, [index_exists?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-index_exists-3F)

The documentation says `index_exists?(table_name, column_name, options = {})`

In `rails console` I tried this...(I knew it wouldn't work)

```
User.index_exists?(:users, :id)
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `index_exists?' for #<Class:0x007f8c113d0cd0>
```

Second try, I got a little smarter...

```
ActiveRecord.index_exists?(:users, :id)
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `index_exists?' for ActiveRecord:Module
```

Third try, I got even smarter!

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements.index_exists?(:users, :id)
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `index_exists?' for ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements:Module
```

Can anyone tell me how to check my database for indexes? And why my last attempt didn't work?

Comment: That method is defined on the subclass ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration of ActiveRecord. So you can't call like the way trying

Comment: This ought to help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25808613/rspec-testing-database-index